# How do I make a context-menu command to output files selected in Explorer as pathnames to a text-file?

Tags: batch-file, contextmenu

When I make a context-menu item in the Registry to call a .bat-file which contains the following command, it doesn't list all the selected files in the outputted .txt-file:

```
echo "%~dpf1" >> "%~dp1filelist-selected.txt"
```

I now realize this is because because Windows opens the .bat-file once for each of the selected files, and if one process tries to run the .bat-file while another process is also running it, then only one of them can access the .txt at any given time, leading to one or more failing to output to the .txt-file.

Does anybody have an idea of how to get around this issue, to get the pathnames of each of the selected files into a single .txt-file?

I see there is a function in Windows called "Copy as path", where the pathnames of selected files are copied to the clipboard.  This option is available as a context-menu item by right-clicking on a selected group of files while holding down the shift-key.

This menu item is described in on the following page: [Show “Copy as Path” Always in Right-Click Menu Without Shift Key](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/copy-as-path-always-show-right-click-windows-10/)

Is there a way one might harness this functionality to make a context-menu command which copies the pathnames of the selected files, makes a .txt-file, and finally pastes the contents of the Clipboard into the file?

I hope somebody has the answer.

Thank you.

Comment: To begin with open a Command Prompt window, type `call /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, to learn what `%~dpf1` resolves to. _`%~dp1` and `%~f1` are essentially resolved to the same value_. However, you should note also that "`%*` in a batch script refers to all the arguments (e.g. `%1` `%2` `%3` `%4` `%5` `...`". So if you are passing multiple 'selected' files, you'd not be using and expanding `%1`, would you?

Answer (score 0):

Your basic batch:

```
FOR %%x in (%*) do IF not %%x == "" (
  ECHO "%%~dpfx" >> "%%~dpxfilelist-selected.txt"
)
```

Comment: Now you can save it in `shell:sendto`, select your files and SEND TO in context-menu. If you just want a linear command to insert in Register, you need to invoke CMD e remove double %%... If ok dont forget to vote.

Comment: If comparisons are literal. If quotes are on one side of the comparison they must be on the other side for the comparison to be true.